# Retrieve output parameter(s) from a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, output-parameter

Trying to run a MS SQL stored procedure that has an output parameter. I have followed documentation on how to do this, but when I run my code I get this error: SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set. Here is my code:

my_stored_procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_stored_procedure]
      @IN1          INT
      @IN2          INT
    , @OUT          INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @OUT = @IN + 1  
END
```

myclass.py

```
  z = sqlalchemy.sql.expression.outparam("ret_%d" % 0, type_=int)
  x = 1
  y = 2
  exec = self.context.\
      execute(text(f"EXEC my_stored_procedure :x, :y, :z OUTPUT"), {"x": x, "y": y, "z": z})
  result = exec.fetchall()
```

context.py

```
   def execute(self, statement, args=None):     
        if not args:
            return self.session.execute(statement)
        else:
            return self.session.execute(statement, args)
```

Any suggestions or can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.outparam()` was added way back in SQLAlchemy 0.4 to address a specific requirement when working with Oracle and is only really used by that dialect. As mentioned in the current SQLAlchemy documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-functions), working with stored procedures is one of the more database/dialect-specific tasks because of the significant variations in the way the different DBAPI layers deal with them.

For SQL Server, the pyodbc Wiki explains how to do it [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures). The good news is that if the stored procedure does not return result sets in addition to the output/return values then you don't need to resort to using a raw DBAPI connection.

For your (corrected) stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_stored_procedure]
      @IN          INT
    , @OUT         INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @OUT = @IN + 1  
END
```

you can use this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199")

sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @out_param int;
EXEC dbo.my_stored_procedure @IN = :in_value, @OUT = @out_param OUTPUT;
SELECT @out_param AS the_output;
"""
with engine.begin() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(sa.text(sql), {"in_value": 1}).scalar()
    print(result)  # 2
```